# Cant get image to stretch full width

Tags: html, css, image, web

I have been having a heck of a time getting a background image to stretch on the screen to fit the screen so I have no decided to just add it as an image. Below is a image of what I am trying to accomplish. I have cleared all of my CSS and HTML for that section and looking to start from scratch again. Thanks so much for the help. 
www.jobspark.ca

[image]

Comment: #site > .wrapper {
    max-width: 960px;
}

this is what stops the image with a fixed width

Comment: you can use firebug to identify these types of issues easily

Comment: @Sanath, Thanks, but when I change the 960 to 100% how to I keep the text from extending across the page. I would like the text to remain at a width of 960px

Comment: have a separate div with a separate style to contain text and that style can have max-width

Answer (score 1):

your parent container already fixed width by 960px. and if you change your container width it will affect your whole design. better try my below code. make position absolute your image and you can stretch

```
.image-block-outer-wrapper{
     height:338px;
 }
.image-block-wrapper{
     position:absolute:
     //align this div using margin
}
 .image-block-wrapper img{
  width:1200px;
   //or increase original image width by photoshop and set width here whatever you want
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have the image stretched across the width of the page and are happy to have the image height scale proportionally try -

```
.image-block-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
.image-block-wrapper img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Please ensure that the "image-block-wrapper" element is not nested inside any other element which has a fixed width. Additionally the  tag should not have width and height attributes specified.